# SPSS .sav file not reading into SAS

Tags: import, sas, export, spss

Attached here is my very simple code to read in .sav files into SAS for analysis.

```
PROC IMPORT
  DATAFILE='C:\Users\Desktop\Iliu_SAS_Files_Relocated\0310_HPV-Boys\SPSS Files\BoyVacuptake.sav'
  OUT=work.BoyVacuptake
  DBMS=SAV REPLACE;
```

The error code that I keep getting is:

> ERROR: DBMS type SAV not valid for import.

I am running SAS 9.4 which should allow me to import/export SPSS files using the DBMS=SAV option. Does anyone know why I may be getting this error? Or any fixes?

I've tried using the DBMS=SPSS option as well, same error. Probably going to try to just read everything into R and export into SAS from there. Need to convert everything to a .sas7bdat file. The .sav files are from an external partner, I do not have access to SPSS to just save the data in a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have SAS/Access to PC Files licensed and installed. Run PROC SETINIT to see what you have licensed.

Second try using SPSS as the DBMS= setting as this documentation page says:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acpcref/n1h6b01uh0dm2yn1fpq85gjgwcfs.htm

**Importing and Exporting SPSS Files**

SPSS Files (DBMS=SPSS)

The IMPORT and EXPORT procedures support two DBMS= identifiers for SPSS .sav files. The DBMS=SPSS specification uses SPSS file formats to access data in SPSS .sav files on UNIX and Microsoft Windows operating platforms.

Comment: So my only SAS/Access is to "Interface to ODBC", do I need a separate license for access to PC files?

Comment: Yes.  Talk to your local SAS admins.  You might need to look for some third party transfer tools.  I know that STATTRANSFER works, but that also probably costs money.